# CSS: "overflow: hidden" doesn't work

Tags: html, css, web

This is my code:

```
.image4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;

    vertical-align: middle;
}
img:hover {
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: click to see printscreen]

As you can see the right side doesn't overflow. What I want is that the photo will zoom without changing the size of the photo.

Comment: Use fixed width and limit it 100% by `max-width`

Comment: If you can post a code snippet it would be easy for us to answer

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: hidden;
```

isn't what you're looking for. The page doesn't know that the image is overflowing because that's just how big the image is in width. Try shrinking the image instead.